# A class of 20 students has 55% girls. The top 3 students are felicitated with gold, silver and bronze medals.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

> In how many ways would the medals be distributed if there are atleast $2$ girls among top $3$?

Will the answer be: $$3!\times\left(\binom {11}{3} + 9\times\binom{11}{2}\right)= 3960$$ or: $$3!\times\left(\binom {11}{2}\times\binom{18}{1}\right) = 5940$$(At least $2$ girls and any other person)

Comment: Use LaTeX please.

Comment: Why did you take away in your edit the two possibilities? They were somehow witnesses of the fact that you tried to find out yourself (as you should). Now your question "asks" for closing (no effort of your own).

Comment: Was trying to learn LaTeX as I was unaware how to write it in that format.

Comment: If you roll the edit back then I will edit your question. No effort is worse than no LaTeX.

Comment: Have tried to edit it as required. Can you help me with what scenarios would be repeated in the 2nd case? @drhab

Comment: Suppose you first select girls $A$ and $B$ and then select out of the remaining $18$ you select $C$ which happens to be a girl as well. Then the result is $\{A,B,C\}$. This result also arises if you first select $A$ and $C$ and then out of the remaining $18$ you select $B$. So $\{A,B,C\}$ is counted at least twice.

Comment: Thank You @drhab

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

There are $3!\times\binom {11}{3}$ ways to give them all to girls. To give exactly two, choose  a boy and two girls in one of $9\times\binom{11}{2}$ ways, and permute the medals. So the answer is $6(165+9\times 55)=3960$.

Comment: Won't we have to choose the girls as well?

Comment: @NischalShah Thanks; fixed.

Comment: Can I use $\binom {11}{2}$ ways to choose 2 girls and then the last person can be choosen in $\binom {18}{1}$ which will give the answer 5940?

Comment: @NischalShah That approach double-counts (well, technically triple-counts) because each two-girls solution could be described in three different ways with that approach; it comes down to which girl you hold until last. Indeed, $6(3\times 165+9\times 55)=5940$.

Answer (score 0):

There are $4$ cases:

- girls receive gold, silver and bronze.
- girls receive gold and silver and no bronze.
- girls receive gold, bronze and no silver.
- girls receive silver, bronze and no gold.

For the first mentioned we find $11\times10\times9=990$ possibilities.

For the others coincidently the same: $11\times10$ possibilities for the girls multiplied with $9$ possibilities for the boys.

So there are $4\times990=3960$ possibilities.

---

The second answer is not correct. See my comment on your question.

Comment: Can I use $\binom {11}{2}$ ways to choose 2 girls and then the last person can be choosen in $\binom {18}{1}$ which will give the answer 5940?

Comment: No. That will lead to multiple counting. The same possibility will be counted more than once.